# Maquina virtual Android

Tags: android, eclipse

Al iniciar la maquina virtual de Android me sale esto :

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Samsung_Galaxy_Tab'
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine
```

Porque puede ser? He intentado cambiarlo todo pero sigue igual. Un saludo.

Comment: Elige una imagen que soporte "hardware acceleration". Si no tienes otras, abre la interfaz de versiones e instala una imagen que lo soporte.

Comment: A que te refieres con imagen? Es que estoy un poco verde en esto.

Comment: La imagen virtual de la maquina. La ISO vamos. Cuando configuras una nueva máquina virtual, tienes un desplegable para escoger la imagen a utilizar.

Comment: En el SDK Manager puedes instalar más imágenes de las versiones de android que utilices. El SDK Manager puedes encontrarlo en el directorio que tengas instalado el SDK de android.

Comment: @Ruben, te sugiero agregar al menos imagen o código en las preguntas que realices, esto para que sea de ayuda a más usuarios y tengas mejores respuestas, revisa [ask].

Comment: Rubén, como le comento a @Jorgesys en su respuesta, si tu procesador es AMD no te va a funcionar la aceleración por hardware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAXM se refiere a Administrador Intel de ejecución acelerada de hardware., en este caso cuando intentas inicializar tu Android Virtual Device (AVD) muestra el mensaje :

> Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Samsung_Galaxy_Tab'
>   emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine

ya que seguramente no esta instalado.

En versiones anteriores de Android Studio 2.0 era suficiente con instalarlo desde el Android SDK Manager, ahora para instalarlo en Android Studio, ve a `File` > `Settings` > `Android SDK` > `SDK Tools` y ve a Intel x86 Emulatir Accelerator (HAXM installer):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Más información:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html

Comment: Yo añadiría a tu respuesta que si el procesador es un AMD, lamentablemente no va a poder utilizar la aceleración de hardware en x86, solo en Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25263563/579895